# Vandermonde matrix whose elements are different roots of unity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, cayley-hamilton

I am solving the following linear system:

$$c_q=\sum_ka_{k,q} f_k\\ a_{k,q}=\exp\left({2 \pi i\frac{k}{q+1}}\right)$$

with $ 0\leq k\leq m,0\leq q\leq m$. For this, it would be useful to calculate its determinant, eigenvalues, eigenvectors and inverse. It seems to me that such a matrix should be well documented in the literature, however I could not find a reference.

**What is the solution to the above linear system?**

So far I have the following: Numerical evidence suggests that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\det(a_{k,q})=0$ and $\forall m, \det(a_{k,q})\neq0$. Therefore, it seems that the homogeneous problem, $c_q=\vec{0}$, has only the trivial solution $f_k=\vec{0}$ unless we are dealing with the infinite case.

EDIT

Thanks to the comment by Paul Garret, I have found that for this Vandermonde matrix, we have

$$\det(a)=\prod_{1\le j<l\le n} (\exp\left(2 \pi i/l \right)-\exp\left(2 \pi i/j \right))$$

Similarily, [this article](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Inverse_of_Vandermonde_Matrix) gives the matrix inverse. This allows to find the seeked solution at least for the finite dimensional case, since the determinant is never null. However, **does the solution hold when $n\to\infty$?**.

Comment: Google "Vandermonde determinant/matrix"...

Comment: So, what is your _actual question_??